# Как отправить данные по почте из формы?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Как отправить данные на почту в вордрессе?
По клику на странице выскакивает вот такое окно, после нажатия кнопки "Купить", не отправляет на почту ничего. Подскажите как можно исправить?!

```
<div style="display: none" id="modal_oneclick" class="modal">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="heading">
            <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
            <h4>Купить в 1 клик</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="product">
            <p class="product-name">ЦЕПИ ПРОТИВОСКОЛЬЖЕНИЯ "ВНЕДОРОЖНИК"</p>
            <div class="select">
                <ul class="tabs__caption">
                    <li class="active">Легковая</li>
                    <li>Кроссовер</li>
                    <li>Внедорожник</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="quantity">
                <p>Количество:</p>
                <ul class="tabs__caption">
                    <li class="active">4</li>
                    <li>6</li>
                    <li>8</li>
                    <li>10</li>
                    <li>12</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="sum">
                <p>Стоимость: <span>4 590 р.</span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Фамилия, Имя*" required="">
            <input class="phone-mask" type="text" placeholder="Телефон*" required="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Адрес">
            <button class="btn">Купить</button>
            <label for="check-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check-1" class="element-checkbox" name="check-1" required>
                <a href="politika-konfidentsialnosti.pdf" target="_blank">Я согласен с условиями обработки моих персональных данных <span>(ознакомиться)</span>*</a>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Скриншот
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чем/как сделана форма? И вообще - какой плагин ИМ если используется?

Comment: дело в том, что написано написано все в одном файле (лединг) и если подключать тот же woocommerce, то ничего не выводит. человек, который писал просто пропал и не доделал. сейчас все написано в index.php

Comment: Тогда код обработчка формы добавьте в вопрос. Не  html-код, а php. И где он вообще есть (в каком файле темы)

Comment: вот index.php  https://pastebin.com/0F6rsYVk , а вот main.js 
 https://pastebin.com/F3t6KgtZ

Comment: Всё сделано неправильно (даже форма) а обработчика вообще нет.

Comment: я сама в шоке. просмотрела кучу уроков, но ничего не работает, из-за кривой верстки. Что можно сделать в данном случае? и если можно пример

Comment: Что можно.. нужно сделать и сделать правильно. Сейчас это просто фикция.

Comment: В даном случае нучно дописать обработчик ajax при клике на отправку формы, а конкретней, js код\файл, который будет отсылать запрос в функцию php, которая будет отсылать письмо с данными, которые ей пришли.

Comment: а можете пример какой ниб привести или видео скинуть?